# How can I create a simple non-CRUD resource action with Drupal 7 / Services 3?

Tags: services

The resource "username" appears but my action does not appear in the list in services admin. Response to a POST is HTTP/1.1 404 Not found: Could not find resource username.

I replaced my module name with "module" here:

```
function module_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'username' => array(
      'check' => array(
        'help' => 'Checks username for uniqueness',
//       'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
       'callback' => '_module_username_check',
       'access callback' => '_module_resource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('view'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'type' => 'string',
            'description' => 'The username to check',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      )
    )
  );
}


function _module_resource_access($op, $args) {
  return TRUE;
}


function _module_username_check($data) {

  $username = $data->username;

  $user = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE name=':username'", array(":username" => $username)));

  return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions outside the normal CRUD roster must be wrapped in an array under the key 'actions'

```
function module_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'actions' => array(
      'username' => array(
...
```

Comment: For future readers (I don't know older versions, but) service 3.x provides both actions and targeted_actions to achieve this task. The former are performed directly on the resource type, the latter on a individual resource. So take care of this when choosing (read docs/services.services.api.php to get further info about this).