# Non-CRUD resource action with Drupal 7 / Services 3

Tags: services, 8

I can't get this simple example working with a custom action.

I had to move it form here [How can I create a simple non-CRUD resource action with Drupal 7 / Services 3?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/how-can-i-create-a-simple-non-crud-resource-action-with-drupal-7-services-3) to an own question.

The example looks like this for CRUD retrieve:

```
function mymod_services_resources() {
 $api = array(
   'test' => array(
     'operations' => array(
       'retrieve' => array(
         'help' => 'Drupal 7 Services 3 test',
         'callback' => '_mymod_test',
         'access callback' => 'user_access',
         'access arguments' => array('access content'),
         'access arguments append' => FALSE,
         'args' => array(
           array(
             'name' => 'fn',
             'type' => 'string',
             'description' => 'Function to perform',
             'source' => array('path' => '0'),
             'optional' => TRUE,
             'default' => '0',
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
  return $api;
}

function _mymod_test($fn) {
  return "Test is working";
}
```

This works fine and returns for http://myhost.dev/endpoint/test/retrieve

`Test is working`

But when i try a custom action like this

```
function mymod_services_resources() {
 $api = array(
   'test' => array(
     'actions' => array(
       'custom' => array(
         'help' => 'Drupal 7 Services 3 test',
         'callback' => '_mymod_test',
         'access callback' => 'user_access',
         'access arguments' => array('access content'),
         'access arguments append' => FALSE,
         'args' => array(
           array(
             'name' => 'fn',
             'type' => 'string',
             'description' => 'Function to perform',
             'source' => array('path' => '0'),
             'optional' => TRUE,
             'default' => '0',
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
  return $api;
}

function _mymod_test($fn) {
  return "Test is working";
}
```

http://myhost.dev/endpoint/test/custom returns just a 404

When i try it like this

```
function mymod_services_resources() {
 $api = array(
     'actions' => array(
       'custom' => array(
       ...
```

It is not shown in the Services list.

@Clive
Yes, i tried to GET that resource. But when i try to POST

```
curl -i -X POST --header "X-CSRFToken: p2BMMItuM6QD9HvdPulxS5IBnXDBnczT46VoLLSqJLM" http://myhost.dev/endpoint/test/custom
```

i get a
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not found: Could not find the controller.

But this solution - see the comments new user have to last 8 hours to answer own question :)
yields to an other question.

How can i get the whole path, not just index 0
    'source' => array('path' => '0'),

I like to get all path segments after the controller. in my case

myhost.dev/endpoint/test/foo/bar/1/2/3

i liked to get foo/bar/1/2/3 with index 0 i can get just foo.

Comment: IIRC actions can only be POST'd to, are you trying to GET that resource?

Comment: Hi Clive i tried to GET that resource. But POST is the same. i put the curl above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I don't have to use myhost.dev/endpoint/test/retrieve in the first example. It is posible to use myhost.dev/endpoint/test/Whateveryouwant. So i understand, i can use the retrieve action and it is not mandatory part of the resource path.