# How can I implement a non-CRUD function in hook_service_resources()?

Tags: services, 8

This question is similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91220/non-crud-resource-action-with-drupal-7-services-3) but I don't understand how the URLs are modified enough for the answer there to make sense to me.

The module adds **retrieve** and **index** operations by default.  I am attempting to extend privatemsg_services_resources with an additional option, **unread**.

I have added **unread** to the function as shown below, but I cannot figure out how to access it via URL.

```
function privatemsg_services_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'privatemsg' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'index'    => array(
          'callback'        => '_privatemsg_services_get',
          'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
          'args'            => array(),
        ),
        'unread'    => array(
          'callback'        => '_privatemsg_services_unread_count',
          'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
            'args' => array(
              array(
                'name'        => 'uid',
                'type'        => 'int',
                'description' => t('UID of the user to check the number of unread messages for.'),
                'source'      => array(
                  'path' => 0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        'retrieve' => array(
          'callback' => '_privatemsg_services_get_thread',
          'access arguments' => array(
            'get private messages from remote',
          ),
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name'        => 'thread_id',
              'type'        => 'int',
              'description' => t('ID of the thread to be retrieved.'),
              'source'      => array(
                'path' => 0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

When I go to **www.myexample.com/drupalgap/privatemsg**, I get the value for **index**.

When I go to **www.myexample.com/drupalgap/privatemsg/THREAD_ID**, I get the **retrieve** value for THREAD_ID.

When I go to **www.myexample.com/drupalgap/privatemsg/unread/UID** or **www.myexample.com/drupalgap/privatemsg/unread**, I get the message `["Invalid parameters passed."]`.

However, if I comment out the function for **retrieve** and then rename **unread** to **retrieve** (to test my code for **unread**), after clearing the caches, going to  **www.myexample.com/drupalgap/privatemsg/UID** gives me the number of unread messages.  So the code is OK, I'm just setting up the resource the wrong way.

How can I call both **retrieve** and **unread** from the URL?

Comment: The key is to use the `actions` array instead of the `operations` array when creating non-CRUD resources. Here's an example for DrupalGap: http://www.drupalgap.org/node/187 - FYI, all calls must use POST when using `actions`. When using `operations` the calls are directed based on the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the `actions` array instead of the `operations` array when creating non-CRUD resources.

Here's an example for DrupalGap: http://drupalgap.org/node/187

FYI, all calls must use `POST` when using `actions`.

When using `operations`, the calls are directed based on the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

Don't forget to attach the `X-CSRF-Token` header to your `POST` calls. Its value can be retrieved here: `?q=services/session/token`

Since this is for DrupalGap, and you're passing along an argument to your service resource, I'd recommend following these instructions, that way jDrupal can be utilized and your function(s) can easily be re-used:

http://drupalgap.org/node/203