# GET request of more than one resource

Tags: services

I'm working with services 7.x-3.12, I need to create a web service in order to get a kind of "associative request" between : books(table stored in db) and categories(another table) those two tables are linked by entity_id

I can GET books (retreive, index) same for categories, but how to get Book A -> categorie A ? or the book list of category A

How can I make it work (the get service)?
P.S. book is a content type (node), categories are taxonomy(taxonomy_term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, [you can't](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/147699/10645). I have [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2537968) posted to hopefully make this, and other filters, a reality soon.

In the mean time, you can however [create a custom service resource](http://www.drupalgap.org/node/187) that uses *POST*, and from there build a custom callback function to return your desired results.

Alternatively, you can use the Views JSON module (a sub module of [Views datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource)) or [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) to easily create a View (with contextual filters, normal filters, sorts, etc) that returns **JSON** data to you via *GET*.

Comment: Thank you tyler, I think I'll follow you on creating a custom service resource

Comment: Here where I'm now (following "create a custom service resource") I've got my_module resource displayed with the action you made in your example (get_user_count). in my case I want the CRUD (only the create) to be displayed, I now I'm supposed to implement the hook resource with the function that insert into my table (db) but what's the best way to make it work? can I perform it with : db_merge ?

Comment: CRUD is only for entities, so your custom callback can do whatever you want. If you need to insert stuff into the database that is fine, you can use any Database API functions to make that happen.

Comment: Sorry tyler, I know you've got enough of my questions I'm sorry, I just want db_insert (or db_merge) in my callback function (the function that create a new record in my custom table) it's a table that contains a list of customers, a customer must create an account by filling out a form (on a mobile app) this form contains exactly what the table "customers" contain of course, i've added args to function customers_services_resources(), args are : name,sexe,age. now how the function customers_create($name, $sexe, $age) could be ? $query = db_merge('cutomers','c') [what next??]

Comment: I'd recommend using db_insert() instead, or make a new question asking about db_merge(). I personally have never used db_merge().

Comment: Ok, db_insert, I'm trying for 5 hours with the callback function ( function customers_create($name, $sexe, $age), can you advice me how to put the arguments on the query please ?

Comment: This page should be helpful: https://www.drupal.org/node/310079

Comment: Thanks Tyler, it works with db_merge (cause I wanted to avoid duplicating records and db_merge is good for that) so thank you I've combined all your advices with other things I created, thanks again