# Can't see resource in Services admin menu after adding hook in the module

Tags: 7, services

I'm adding Services integration to the [room_reservations](https://www.drupal.org/project/room_reservations) module. I added the hook to the module like this:

room_reservations.module

```
function room_reservations_services_resources(){
  $room_service = array(
    'room_reservations'=>array(
      'operations'=>array(
        'retrieve'=>array(
          'help'=>'Gets the hours and the days reservations can be made',
          'file'=>array(
            'type'=>'inc',
            'module'=>'room_reservations',
            'name'=>'room_reservations'
            ),
          'callback'=>'_room_reservations_facility_hours',
          'access arguments'=>array('get reservation hours'),
          'access arguments append'=>FALSE,
          'args'=>array(
            'name'=>'reset',
            'type'=>'string',
            'description'=>'reset',
            'optional'=>TRUE,
            'source'=>'data'
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  return $room_service;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't see the custom service.

Also, by reading the docs on the Services module, could this be done as an action? if so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you clear the cache and added .inc file?

Comment: You'll have to use an action instead, see this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/147699/10645 - otherwise check out this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity